# Volume of a curve rotated around the y-axis

Tags: calculus, volume, area

> "Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y = 3+2x-x^{2}$ and $y+x=3$ about the y-axis. Below is a graph of the bounded region."

I graphed it and it turned out as a cone. area of cone $= 1/3(\pi r^2 h)$
but i don't know what the radius is for the integral equation? but the cylindrical method would imply the use of $(\pi r^2 h)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a cone, did you lose the parabola? It's a strange rotated displaced parabola (an overturned curved cup with an indentation at the top), with a cone *cut out of it at the bottom*.

The curves intersect at $x=0$ and $x=3$, so you maximal radius will be $3$. Your volume lies between the strange outer thingy and the inner cone.

---

You can solve for volumes of surfaces of revolution in more than one way. If you slice the volume into thin disks and integrate over them (best for revolution around $x$ axis, $V=\int \pi y(x)^2\,dx$ where $y(x)$ is the radius of the current disk). However, the method of cylindrical shells works better for revolution around $y$. Instead of thin disks, it sums over cylindrical shells, as suggested by the name:

$$2\pi\int xf(x)\,dx$$

Which uses $f(x)$ as the height of the cylinder and $2\pi x$ as its circumference. This implies the bottom side of the volume sits at $y=0$ (flat bottom on the floor).

If the surface extends between curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the height of the shell in question is the difference $f(x)-g(x)$.

$$2\pi\int x(f(x)-g(x))\,dx$$

Now just plug it in:

$$2\pi \int_0^3 x((3+2x-x^2)-(3-x))\,{\rm d}x$$

Comment: thank u orion soooo much makes sooo much sense!!!!

Comment: @user132138 My pleasure. You can accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: how do  i accept??

Comment: To the left of the answer, you see arrows for voting and a checkmark you can click to make it green.

Comment: is a similar theory applied to this q?Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the curves y = 3+2x-x^{2} and y+x=3 about the y-axis.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same question?

Comment: wrong q sorry.... Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves y=x^2, x=3, and y=0 about the x-axis.

Comment: That's the other method that I mentioned above (disks & washers). I told you for a disk (a single rotated curve), but a volume between two curves is just a difference of two integrals, so again you have $\int \pi (f(x)^2-g(x)^2)\,dx$.

Comment: thanks very mmuch @orion!!